# How to upload photo from expo-image-picker?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, nestjs, multer

I've tried multiple ways to upload photo from `expo-image-picker`, but still don't figure it out. The server is classic nestjs with multer

```
  @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  public addTimelineEventWithSingleImage(
    @Headers('x-token') token: string,
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
    @Body() body: IAddEventBody
  ): Promise<void> {
    console.log('file', file);
    console.log('body', body);
  }
```

the logs are:

```
Mar 5 04:13:00 PM  file undefined
Mar 5 04:13:00 PM  body {
Mar 5 04:13:00 PM    _parts: [
Mar 5 04:13:00 PM      [ 'file', [Object] ],
Mar 5 04:13:00 PM      [ 'description', '' ],
Mar 5 04:13:00 PM      [ 'eventType', 'COMMENT' ]
Mar 5 04:13:00 PM    ]
Mar 5 04:13:00 PM  }
```

I'm creating the formData in various ways

1. from this article as [blob](https://medium.com/@joananespina/uploading-to-firebase-storage-with-react-native-39f4a500dbcb)

```
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', blob);
      formData.append('description', timelineEvent.description);
      formData.append('eventType', timelineEvent.eventType);
```

2. with uri, name and type

```
formData.append('file', {
 name: image.uri.split('/').pop(),
 type: 'image/jpg',
 uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? image.uri : image.uri.replace('file://', ''),
});
```

3. buffer from base64

```
    const formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('file', Buffer.from(image, 'base64'));
     formData.append('description', timelineEvent.description);
     formData.append('eventType', timelineEvent.eventType);
```

I've checked the endpoint with the postman and it works.
Source of the uri is result.assets[0]:

```
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      mediaTypes: MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      selectionLimit: 1,
      allowsEditing: true,
      quality: 0.8,
      base64: true,
      aspect: [1, 1],
      presentationStyle: UIImagePickerPresentationStyle.POPOVER
    });
```

It seems to be simple to upload a photo taken by user, but is not, can anybody help?

Comment: solved by
```
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', { uri: image, name: 'test.jpeg', type: 'image/jpeg' });
    formData.append('description', timelineEvent.description);
    formData.append('eventType', timelineEvent.eventType);
```
I was messing up with the file name (I missed extenstion like filename instead of filename.jpeg) and with the type image/jpg instead of image/jpeg that's why it didn't work